# In R, what does it mean to pass a character vector as the object in rawConnection?

Tags: r, file, binaryfiles

The `rawConnection` function has a [help file](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/rawConnection) that states that first argument, `object`, must be:

> character or raw vector. A description of the connection. For an input
>   this is an R raw vector object, and for an output connection the name
>   for the connection.

My team is using the `rawConnection` function to serialize a data frame held in memory into a CSV file, which is then pushed to an API. Rather than write the CSV file to disk, then read it back in to push it, we simply create a raw representation of the CSV and then send it out. This is all working fine, and while it's not the code we're using, below shows what I'm talking about.

```
# Create fake data
fake_data <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3),
                        b = c(4,5,6),
                        c = c(7,8,9))

# Open a connection to a raw vector
write_rawcon <- rawConnection(object = raw(0),
                              open = "w")

# Write CSV file to the raw vector
write.csv(x = fake_data,file = write_rawcon,row.names = FALSE)

# Access binary representation of CSV
binary_csv <- rawConnectionValue(write_rawcon)

# Close raw connection
close(write_rawcon)

# Read binary back in
read_rawcon <- rawConnection(object = binary_csv,open = "r")
new_binary_csv <- readBin(con = read_rawcon,what = "raw",n = length(binary_csv))


# The binary read in matches the binary from the write connection
identical(x = binary_csv,y = new_binary_csv)

# We can convert the raw to character, and make a text connection back
# Hence, a CSV again
read.csv(file = textConnection(object = rawToChar(new_binary_csv)))
```

I understand (I think anyway) how this is working. It's creating a write-only connection to an empty raw vector, and then sending the output of `write.csv` to that connection (rather than to a file on disk). We can access that binary representation using `rawConnectionValue`, and store it in an object. Later, if we want, we can open a read-only `rawConnection` to that binary object, and use readBin to get the same raw representation that we had before. `rawToChar` plus a `textConnection` lets us move this back to a CSV representation. All of this is making sense to me.

The thing I am struggling to understand is the "**character** or raw vector" part of the instructions. I have not been able to get `rawConnection` to take any type of character input for object. I've tried the following.

## Binary to Character Vector

```
rawConnection(object = as.character(new_binary_csv),
              open = "r")
Error in rawConnection(object = as.character(new_binary_csv), open = "r") : 
  invalid 'raw' argument
```

## Binary to Character String

```
rawConnection(object = paste(new_binary_csv,
                             collapse = ""),
              open = "r")
Error in rawConnection(object = paste(new_binary_csv, collapse = ""),  : 
  invalid 'raw' argument
```

## A File Path - Write Mode

```
rawConnection(object = "C:/valid/path/hello.bin",open = "w")
Error in rawConnection(object = "C:/valid/path/hello.bin",  : 
  invalid 'raw' argument
```

## A File Path - Read Mode

```
rawConnection(object = "C:/valid/path/hello.bin",open = "r")
Error in rawConnection(object = "C:/valid/path/hello.bin",  : 
  invalid 'raw' argument
```

## Serialized Objects Coerced to Character

In confusion I've been trying a few other things. One thing I discovered was that the error message was subtly different if you tried opening a `rawConnection` to an R object you serialized using `serialize`, wrapped in `as.character`. The code works fine if the `serialize` is not wrapped in `as.character` but I assume this is because `serialize` is returning a raw vector. It also seems to matter whether you are telling `serialize` to explicitly return **OR** not return ASCII outputs, which I was confused about as well.

```
more_fake_data <- c(1,2,3,4)
rawConnection(object = as.character(serialize(object = more_fake_data,
                                              connection = NULL,
                                              ascii = TRUE)),
              open = "r")

Error in rawConnection(object = as.character(serialize(object = more_fake_data,  : 
  invalid 'description' argument

rawConnection(object = as.character(serialize(object = more_fake_data,
                                              connection = NULL,
                                              ascii = FALSE)),
              open = "r")

Error in rawConnection(object = as.character(serialize(object = more_fake_data,  : 
  invalid 'description' argument

rawConnection(object = as.character(serialize(object = more_fake_data,
                                              connection = NULL)),
              open = "r")

Error in rawConnection(object = as.character(serialize(object = more_fake_data,  : 
  invalid 'raw' argument
```

As can be seen, the first two return an invalid 'description' argument error, but the last returns an invalid 'raw' argument error.

At this point I am fairly confused about what exactly the help file means when it says that the function can take a character or raw vector. I think I understand how the binary data is being moved around, but for whatever reason I can't seem to wrap my head around how you would pass a character argument to the first part of `rawConnection`. How would you do this? What does the help file mean when it says that the function can accept a character or raw vector, and what would that look like in code?

EDITED TO ADD: In response to a comment, I did try using a character string to name the connection. However, this didn't work, unless I was completely misunderstanding what I was supposed to do. I thought the point of the `rawConnection` was to create the connection, but if you give it something like this, you get an error:

```
rawcon <- rawConnection(object = "myconnection",open = "w")

Error in rawConnection(object = "myconnection", open = "w") : 
  invalid 'raw' argument
```

If you're supposed to give it the name of an existing connection, how are you supposed to create the connection in the first place? Why would you be using `rawConnection` to create a connection that you already have? I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something here - I'm hoping someone has a working example that will clear things up.

Comment: You've quoted the explanation from the docs: "For an input this is an R raw vector object, and for an output connection the name for the connection." Thus in read-mode, it takes a raw vector of data; for write modes, it takes a character vector of the name of the connection. I'm not sure any of this is necessary, though, as if you can use `textConnection` to save a character vector of a CSV as a variable, e.g. `write.csv(mtcars, textConnection('x', 'w'))`, avoiding both writing to disk and serialization.

Comment: I guess this is part of the confusion, because "output mode" (i.e. write mode) takes `raw(0)` without difficulty, which is not a character vector. Also, if you try to use `rawConnection(object = "object",open = "w")`, you get the same "invalid 'raw' argument". Also, for clarity, the method we are using wants a binary representation passed to the function, hence why we are doing this. :) Also: I have edited my question for more clarity on this.

Comment: It looks like the documentation is wrong. The [C code checks that the class is RAW](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/eed18df7ebc864d83fe8c9f0fb81b12aa29cd464/src/main/connections.c#L2862). Doesn't seem to be possible to pass a character value to `rawConnection`

Comment: Yeah, trying it out, it's sort of weird. In writing modes, the quoted input is used as the description, but as far as I can tell, the only way to get the data back out is with `rawConnectionValue`, which seems...not right.